# What was the poem Tagore wrote in Satyendranath Dutta's memory?

Tags: identification-request, poetry, rabindranath-tagore, bengali-language

[Satyendranath Dutta's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyendranath_Dutta) says that Rabindranath Tagore wrote a poem in his honor after his death. It cites [*The Report*](https://www.thereport.live/arts/satyendranath-dutta-the-wizard-of-rhymes/13708), which says:

> Rabindranath Tagore has immortalized Satyendranath in a poem written after his death. Kazi Nazrul Islam also wrote a poem titled 'Satyendranath' eulogizing his death.

I can find a few other related references for this; Tagore and Dutta certainly seem to have met, worked together, and moved in the same circles, but I am yet to find the poem itself. Searching `site:tagoreweb.in satyendranath` gives 744 results, most of which are in Bangla and of dubious relevance. Perhaps I'm not searching correctly...

In any case, what was the poem that Tagore wrote in Dutta's memory?

Comment: One of Rabindranath's kid brothers was named Satyendranath. He's well known for being the first Indian in the Indian Civil Service. Additionally, he too was a poet of some distinction. If you search for "Satyendranath" on tagoreweb.in, you're gonna get hundreds of results about him, natch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a long poem called "[সত্যেন্দ্রনাথ দত্ত / Satyendranath Datta](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.356913/page/n31/mode/2up)". The poem was published in Tagore's 1925 collection *[পূরবী / Puravi](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.356913/mode/2up)*. The date of composition given at the end of the poem is "আষাঢ়, ১৩২৯ / aaShaaDh, 1329", which [corresponds](https://www.bangladatetoday.com/calendar.php?year=1329) to mid-June to mid-July of the Gregorian year 1922. Since Dutta died on 25 June of that year, Tagore's poem must have been written very shortly thereafter.